# How to automatically display new sms in listview using gsm modem?

Tags: c#, listview, sms

So far i have this code

```
 public void read()
    {
        //port is already open
        port.Write("AT" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        port.Write("AT+CMGF=1" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        port.Write("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"\r" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        //Thread.Sleep(3000);
        //MessageBox.Show(port.ReadExisting());


        Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n(.+)\r\n");
        Match m = r.Match(port.ReadExisting());
        while (m.Success)
        {
            string a = m.Groups[1].Value;
            string b = m.Groups[2].Value;
            string c = m.Groups[3].Value;
            string d = m.Groups[4].Value;
            string ee = m.Groups[5].Value;
            string f = m.Groups[6].Value;

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { a, b, c, d, ee, f });
            lvwMessages.Items.Add(item);
            m = m.NextMatch();
        }
        lvwMessages.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
        lvwMessages.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
        sd.Width = 0;
    }
```

this code gets triggered in a button click event, what im wondering is, is it possible to automatically display new sms without repeatedly calling read() in a timer? using timer causes the listview to blink and lose its selection.

i am working on a winform by the way.

Comment: User the serial port port.DataReceived() method which is asynchronous.

Comment: i kinda solved it but still using timer, tho it adds it to the listview instead of clearing all items and then adding them again. i only add thos sms with "REC UNREAD" status. i appreciate your answer and i believe your answer is correct. tho im a beginner at this. im not that familiar with datareceived methods and at commands

Comment: See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx